# c# wpf - unit calculation in code

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to implement a calculation that goes as follow:

I have 53 minutes and want to calculate units based on this criteria:

1 unit is 15 minutes but every 8 minutes I'm at the next unit.

So in essence, 53 minutes is 4 units and it's not until 68 minutes that I'm at the next unit.

7 minutes is 0 units.. 8 minutes is 1 unit but I'm at 1 unit until I reach 16 minutes

any ideas

Comment: i think i may confused my answer. you saying one unit is 15 min but it changes every 8 min. Below code does this 0 min to 22min = 1 unit, 23 - 37 = 2 units, 38-52 = 3 units, 53-57 = 4 units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
decimal minutes = functiontogetyourminutes();
int unit = 0;

if (minutes <23)
{ 
unit = 1;
}
else
{
    decimal temp = minutes/15;
    unit = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round(temp,  MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
}
        }
    }
}
```

please see that minutes are specified as double so result from division is a decimal.

if you want to have 0 units for 7 min and below:

```
decimal minutes = functiontogetyourminutes();
int unit = 0;
decimal temp = minutes/15;
unit = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round(temp,  MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Comment: Claudius, i believe this is what I'm looking for. To clarify your answer above, 0-7 is 0 units, 8-22 is 1 unit, 23-37 is 2 units, 38-52 is 3 units, 53-68 is 4 units and so on. Thanks for your help

Comment: any idea what the midpointrounding.awayfromzero equivalent is in T-SQL? @Claudius

Comment: @Walking I wouldn't know about T-SQL, just a note 68 would be 5 units

Comment: @Walking See my updated answer for the T-SQL version.

Answer (score 2):

```
int minutes = 53;
int units =  (minutes + 7) / 15;
```

The equivalent in SQL Server would be:

```
declare @minutes int = 53
declare @units int 

select @units = (@minutes + 7) / 15.00

print @units
```